# Get an associated collections via RPC

Tags: corda

We have two states stored in Corda Vault (policy and event). Policy can have many events associated with it.
We are attempting to get a joined result (as if we run SQL with `JOIN` statement) via RPC client and we can't find a graceful way: either we should make several `VaultQueries` or just use direct JDBC connection to the underlying database and extract the required data. Neither of ways looks appealing and we wonder if there is a good way to extract the data.

As we cannot use JPA/Hibernate annotations to link objects inside the CordApp, we have just `policy_id` stored in event state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more complex queries, it is fine and even expected that the user will query the node's database directly using the JDBC connection.